# Automatic heading in React with Strapi

Tags: reactjs, cmd, strapi

I am developing an React site with Strapi as CMS. I am very lazy and want that React knows when strapi is creating an heading.

Strapi export h1, h2, h3 as #, ##, ### etc. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPgbs.png)

It is possible that react parting and syling it automatticly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown).